# Mathematica: Removing graphics primitives

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given that `g` is a graphics object with primitives such as `Line`s and `Polygon`s, how do you remove some of them? To add more primitives to an existing graphics object we can use `Show`, for instance: `Show[g, g2]` where `g2` is another graphics object with other primitives. But how do you remove unwanted primitive objects? Take a look at the following

```
ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, Mesh -> {1, 1}]
```

[image: Output]

Now, for the input form:

```
InputForm[
   ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, Mesh -> {1, 1}]
 ]
```

[image: Output]

To create a wire frame from this object all we have to do is remove the polygons. As an extra we can also remove the vertex normals since they don't contribute to the wireframe.

Notice that to make a wireframe we can simply set `PlotStyle -> None` as an option in `ListPlot3D`. This gets rid of the `Polygon`s but doesn't remove the `VertexNormals`.

To clarify the question. Given that

```
 g = ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, Mesh -> {1, 1}]
```

How do you remove some of the of the graphics primitives from `g` and how do you remove some of the options, i.e. `VertexNormals`? Note: option `VertexNormals` is an option of `GraphicsComplex`.

If this is not possible then maybe the next question would be, how do you obtain the data used to generate `g` to generate a new graphics object with some of the data obtained from `g`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use transformation rules. Given your

```
im = ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}},  Mesh -> {1, 1}]
```

You can do

```
newim = im /. {_Polygon :> Sequence[], (VertexNormals -> _) :> Sequence[]}
```

or, more compactly using [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html):

```
newim = im /. _Polygon | (VertexNormals -> _) :> Sequence[]
```

You could also use `DeleteCases` to get a similar effect:

```
newim = DeleteCases[im, (_Polygon | (VertexNormals -> _)), Infinity]
```

[image]

Comment: @Leonid, well now I feel pretty dumb. Thank you for showing me all these different ways.

Comment: Leonid, is there any reason to leave the verbose form in your post?  To me it just adds confusion.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I had an impression  that less experienced users will find the first one easier to understand. I may be wrong.

Comment: Leonid, you surprise me, because in a prior exchange you said: "... it seems a little inelegant to give a name for the pattern if that name is never used. For someone not fully understanding the reasons for that, your intentions may look unclear, as if something was planned but forgotten."

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, you are right, regarding pattern names - those are not needed, I will edit to remove them. I rather meant a list of rules - seems easier to grasp than combining patterns with `Alternatives`. And as I said, I may be wrong.

Comment: I like that better.  I added a link to Alternatives help; I hope you don't mind.