# Mathematica: Obtaining graphics primitives and directives

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

How do you obtain graphic primitives and directives from a `Graphics` object? Leonid Shifrin showed how to remove them in the post [Mathematica: Removing graphics primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317253/mathematica-removing-graphics-primitives). I tried applying something similar but I can't get what I want. Consider this example:

```
 g1 = ListPlot3D[
    {{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}},
    Mesh -> {2, 2},
    Boxed -> False,
    Axes -> False,
    ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 1},
    ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1},
    MeshStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0],
    BoundaryStyle -> RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0]
 ];
 g2 = ImportString[ExportString[g1, "PDF", Background -> None], "PDF"][[1]]
```

[image: output]

`g2` is now a graphics object. If you look at the `InputForm` of `g2` you will see that this graphics object is composed of `Polygon`s and `JoinedCurve`s.  What I would like to do is able to iterate through all of the primitive objects of `g2`. If we try to iterate as follows

```
 objs = First[g2];
 Table[Head[objs[[i]]], {i, 1, Length@objs}]
```

we obtain

```
 {Thickness, Polygon, Polygon, Polygon, Polygon, Style, Style, Style, Style, 
  Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, 
  Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, 
  Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, Style, 
  Style, Style, Style}
```

What I would like to obtain instead is a list of simple primitives, I do not want them inside `Styles`. Here is one attempt obtaining only the lines and colors:

```
 tmp1 = Cases[objs, (_JoinedCurve | _RGBColor), Infinity];
 tmp2 = DeleteCases[objs, (_Polygon | _Thickness), Infinity];
 GraphicsRow[{Graphics[tmp1], Graphics[tmp2]}]
```

[image: output]

Notice that the image on the left is drawn incorrectly. This image was generated using only `JoinedCurve`s and `RGBColor`s. It somehow managed to miss one color, that is why we have a black line and then the rest of lines have the other color. The other image is drawn correctly, all we did was delete all the `Polygons` and `Thickness` that appeared in there. What am I doing differently here? Shouldn't we obtain the same plots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read:

> What I would like to obtain instead is
>   a list of simple primitives, I do not
>   want them inside `Styles`.

You can get it just by simple replacement:

```
First[ g2 /. Style[expr_, opts___] :> {opts, expr} ]
```

---

Now you write:

> Here is one attempt obtaining only the
>   lines and colors

Knowing the internal structure of `g2` it is simple to extract only `Line` objects with its colors. It is even simpler because all `Line`s are wrapped with `Style`:

```
tmp3 = Cases[g2, 
   Style[{lines__Line}, ___, color_RGBColor, ___] :> {color, lines}, 
   Infinity];
Graphics[tmp3]
```